# Replacing all Hex numbers with Decimal representation

Tags: c#, regex, hex, decimal

I have a string: `string s ="My Favorite numbers are: 42, 0x42, 24 and 0x24"`
Is there a way using Regex to replace all hex numbers to their Decimal representation?

For the example above, I would expect to get: `"My Favorite numbers are: 42, 66, 24 and 36"`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this (*regular expression* and *conversion*):

```
String source = "My Favorite numbers are: 42, 0x42, 24 and 0x24";

String result = Regex.Replace(source, @"0x(\d|[a-f]|[A-F])+", 
  (MatchEvaluator) (match => Convert.ToInt32(match.Value, 16).ToString()));
```

I've assumed that all the hex numbers are *non-negative* and *small enough* to be `int`.