# How to use decimal entity codes in XML instead of hexadecimal entity codes

Tags: c#, xml

In my C# application, I am reading data from a source which has \r \n characters, and converting them to an XmlDocument. When using the CreateElement method of XmlDocument, it escapes them using hexadecimal entity codes, like `&#xD;` and `&#xA;`.

I have to send this XML to a 3rd party application, which accepts only decimal entity codes. So I have to send as `&#13;` and `&#10;`

How can I configure XmlDocument to use decimal entity codes?

Comment: Use System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(); and System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode();

Comment: Can you give an example? Do I have to use HTML api to build XML? Is there no setting directly inside one of the XML classes?

Comment: No setting.  You have to use the WebUtility to make conversion.  See wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Comment: Hmm, ok. Can you give an example how to use it?

Comment: Are you using a serializer?  A serializer you write custum properties to handle the To() string.

Comment: As I said, I am just using CreateElement and filling the value in the XmlNode

Comment: The problem is if I use any other method to escape the special characters before using CreateElement, example I replace the string \r with &#13;, then CreateElement further escapes the & character and makes it &amp;#13;

Comment: Are you sure you are using the XmlDocument.CreateElement() and not the HtmlDocument.CreateElement() method?  I don't rememeber ever seeing xml value get changed automatically.  Is there code that is adding the #?

Comment: @AllSolutions What is the 3rd party application, which accepts only decimal entity codes in XML?

Comment: Its a proprietory Back Office application

Answer (score 1):

As soon as receiver app is crooked, the easies way is to introduce post-processing step that would bake your XML string to "acceptable" format. So, string.Replace() should help you here for sure. Not efficient, very effective. Sad but true.

Comment: Is there a way to change all hex entity codes to decimal entity codes? I need to call string.Replace() for all possible entity codes. Is there such a string utility? Or any place I can get the complete list of hex entity codes and their decimal equivalents, so that I can load it as a resource file and loop and replace?

Comment: @AllSolutions, you could look for "&#", then use something like that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28274757/replacing-all-hex-numbers-with-decimal-representation

Answer (score 0):

When you have a receiving application that isn't accepting correct XML, the best thing to do is to change the receiving application. (Similarly, if you have a sending application that isn't sending correct XML, it's best to change the sending application). This is what standards are all about: if you want to get the benefits of XML, everyone has to play by the rules.

Producing constrained XML is generally going to be difficult and costly, because it constrains your choice of tools, or you have to write stuff by hand rather than using off-the-shelf software.

I don't think there are many tools that give you control over how numeric character references are written, but one that does is Saxon (PE or higher). You can use the extension property saxon:character-representation as an additional serialization property: see http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!extensions/output-extras/serialization-parameters.

Comment: But the receiving application is accepting correct decimal entity codes. Its only limitation is it is not accepting hexadecimal entity codes. Of course, I can't change the receiving application as it is a third party app.

Comment: If the receiving application is not accepting hexadecimal entity codes then it is not a conformant XML application. (I think we should have a "not-XML" tag on StackOverflow. An awful lot of the problems raised under the XML tag would disappear if people started using XML instead of not-XML).  And saying you can't change it is like saying you can't change a power socket just because it doesn't accept standard power plugs.